# Where can I find a good resource to learn Microsoft Project basics?

Tags: microsoft-project

I want to manage a project (3 people, about a year) in Microsoft Project. So I want to do the basic stuff in MS Project: Create a Gantt chart, and track the progress during the execution.

Any idea, where can I learn the basics of it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many books available.  A start cou;dbe Microsoft Project 2010 Step by Step (Microsoft Press) Available at all better booksellers and online merchants. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of resources available online to learn how to 'operate' Project, however, they do not do a good job of explaining how to 'use' it. If you have the time, you might enroll in a CC class for project management to learn when and why you should do certain things in project. I recently completed a class like this an I learned a ton, and simply reading a Project manual wouldn't have come close to the knowledge gained from an experienced teacher/Project manager.